PhpStorm overwrite " (quote) when it already exists instead of adding another
I have searched for this and it appears to be a common complaint that has yet to be solved -
When typing in PhpStorm, the auto complete generates the ="" for you, which can be quite helpful:
href="|"

And it leaves your cursor (|) in the middle, ready to go.  Great!
However, as has been complained about in the past, in order to then move past that quote, you need to move your hand to your arrow keys and hit the right arrow.
Ideally, what I'd like though, is to set it up so if I press " while right in front of a " it simply overwrites it and moves the cursor through/past it.
Is this possible using any of the mapping functions?
EDIT:  I just noticed that PhpStorm does this with the single quote when editing an array (at least inline)...

Works just fine here in plain .html file. Show what you have at Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys . If I disable Insert pair quote option it will start behaving in the unwanted way (will add another double quote instead of "eating it")

Also check this old answer (mentions some other related options): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303192/783119

@LazyOne Welp look at that, you're right.  It works in HTML.  Just not working in PHP.  I do have "Insert pair quote" checked.


Please provide a small self-contained code sample to reproduce. Ideally a file shared via Google Drive or alike service (in case file has some special characters/specific line break symbols used etc and that matters for this issue) 2) Also show a screenshot of how it looks in the IDE -- it may show some nuances (ideally using default light theme -- I'm more familiar with that color scheme).



If that happens in a Blade file -- maybe it's https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-77626


@LazyOne Yep - that bug is exactly it.  Thanks.

Thanks to @LazyOne in the comments on my post I've discovered it's a known bug.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-77626
